# Change WooCommerce product gallery thumbnails to squares

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the image gallery on a product page to squares. without the need to upload all images with a square format.

like in the image:
[Optimal situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qerke.png)

So it wont look like this:
[Current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8kL2.png)

If its possible to do this with CSS on the elemetor "Custome CSS" or with PHP into the functions.php file, also if its possible to do it with and without cropping the image so i can decide whats looks better.

Thanks :)

I tried adding codes i found on stackoverflow but nothing really worked

Comment: the images are probably croped already depends on the theme or woo which image size is set to use. Since you have different dimension images croping is set to get either width or height without cutting the image. Wordpress by default have square sizes and you can just set this image size to be used instead. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/ https://woocommerce.com/document/image-sizes-theme-developers/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default css for Woocomerce Product Gallery Images is a cropped square. This may be being overwritten by custom css, your theme or plugins.

Can you provide a link to your development site?

You could also try referring to the developers documentation to create a hook to specifically target the gallery thumbnails like this:

```
// Add a filter to modify WooCommerce product gallery thumbnail size.
add_filter('woocommerce_get_image_size_gallery_thumbnail', 'customize_gallery_thumbnail_size');

function customize_gallery_thumbnail_size($size) {
    // Override the default settings with your custom dimensions.
    return array(
        'width'  => 200,
        'height' => 200,
        'crop'   => 1,  // Ensure the image is cropped to fit the exact dimensions.
    );
}
```

https://woocommerce.com/document/image-sizes-theme-developers/